# Configure Message Driven Bean using ejb-jar.xml

Tags: glassfish-3, message-driven-bean, ejb-jar.xml

I am trying to configure Message Driven Bean using ejb-jar. I am using EJB 3.1, Netbeans 7.3 and Glassfish 3.1.2, but I am getting exception:

Exception while deploying the app: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 29; Deployment descriptor file META-INF/ejb-jar.xml in archive [classes].  Element type "messaging-type" must be declared.. Please see server.log for more details.

Where do I make mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you are using Glassfish 3.1.2, but you validate your `ejb-jar-xml` file with `ejb-jar_2_0.dtd`. Instead you must use XSD validation for Glassfish 3.1.2. Here is the xsd:
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd